# If the button is disabled i need to show a div after clicking or mouse over the button

Tags: jquery, html

Here i have an button which is disabled intially after i click or mouse over the disabled the disable button i need to show one div amd my code is in fiddle.

https://jsfiddle.net/L4aczs0b/`12397`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working fiddle with your solution. The thing is, that disabled elements don't trigger jQuery events: https://jsfiddle.net/jonva/L4aczs0b/2/

So you need to have an alias element to take the disable element's place in the DOM:

```
    <div style="display:inline-block; position:relative;">
      <button id="button">submit</button>
      <div style="position:absolute; left:0; right:0; top:0; bottom:0;" id="alias"></div>
   </div>
```

and then trigger the `.fadeIn` function on hover of *that* element

```
$('#alias').hover( function() {
    $("#d").fadeIn(500);
});
$('#alias').mouseout( function() {
    $("#d").fadeOut(500);
});
```

Comment: yeah thanks for your solution but after i click the checkbox and button is enabled then the hover function dont want to display the div

Comment: Updated the fiddle.

Comment: In tha above update after checkbox ix checked the button is enabled it dont want to display the div but it displaying

Comment: ok i changed it but i have another doubt if i click that button to redirect another page it will no go...

Comment: I didn't quite understand. What is the functionality you want to implement?

Comment: In the above function after the enabled button clicked it ashould redirect to another page but it doesnot redirect to another page it remains the same page...